# Round x axis of a time scale to nearest half hour

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image: My current graph]

I'm constructing a graph right now which is taking in data from a postgres backend. For the construction of the x-axis, I have the following:

```
var x = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain(d3.extent(data_prices, function(d){
        var time = timeParser(d.timestamp);
        return time;
    }))
    .range([0,width])
```

where timeParser is a function representing d3.timeParse().

I have a data point which is at 16:58 and another at 22:06 and it looks a little ugly having it just stick at the side like that. How would I say, for instance, have there be a slight padding of say, +/- 30 minutes for each and continue the trendline path on each end? (or at least just the first part)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create a padding in a time scale, use `interval.offset`. According to the [API](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_offset):

> Returns a new date equal to date plus step intervals. If step is not specified it defaults to 1. If step is negative, then the returned date will be before the specified date.

Let's see it working. This is an axis based on a time scale with a min and a max similar to yours:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = ["16:58", "18:00", "20:00", "22:00", "22:06"].map(function(d) {
  return d3.timeParse("%H:%M")(d)
});

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain(d3.extent(data))
  .range([20, 580]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```

Now, to create the padding, we just need to subtract and add 30 minutes at the extremes:

```
var scale = d3.scaleTime()
    .domain([d3.timeMinute.offset(d3.min(data), -30),
        //subtract 30 minutes here --------------^
            d3.timeMinute.offset(d3.max(data), 30)
        //add 30 minutes here ------------------^
        ])
    .range([20, 580]);
```

Here is the result:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = ["16:58", "18:00", "20:00", "22:00", "22:06"].map(function(d) {
  return d3.timeParse("%H:%M")(d)
});

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([d3.timeMinute.offset(d3.min(data), -30), d3.timeMinute.offset(d3.max(data), 30)])
  .range([20, 580]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```

Have in mind that this solution **does not** round the extreme ticks to the nearest half hour: it **adds** and **subtracts** exactly half an hour.

So, to round to the nearest half hour, you can do a simple math using `Math.floor` and `Math.ceil`:

```
.domain([
    d3.min(data).setMinutes(Math.floor(d3.min(data).getMinutes() / 30) * 30), 
    d3.max(data).setMinutes(Math.ceil(d3.max(data).getMinutes() / 30) * 30)
])
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = ["16:58", "18:00", "20:00", "22:00", "22:06"].map(function(d) {
  return d3.timeParse("%H:%M")(d)
});

var scale = d3.scaleTime()
  .domain([d3.min(data).setMinutes(Math.floor(d3.min(data).getMinutes() / 30) * 30), d3.max(data).setMinutes(Math.ceil(d3.max(data).getMinutes() / 30) * 30)])
  .range([20, 580]);

var axis = d3.axisBottom(scale);

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(axis)
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="600" height="100"></svg>
```